# Understanding "update_option_(option_name)" Wordpress hook

Tags: php, wordpress

I am creating a plugin for Wordpress and haven't really worked with Wordpress very long and i want to have a function run once a specific option is updated for a blog. I think that update_option_(option_name) is the hook i want but i can't understand or find how to use it and was wondering if anyone had an example or a link to show me how this hook works?
THANKS!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run over a specific wordpress function or hook name, just go to google and enter:

```
codex *function or hookname*
```

like

```
codex update_option_(option_name)
```

for your question.

Normally the first result directs you to the wordpress documentation page (codex) that normally answers most questions. If not, there are more search results that are most often helpful.

Additionally, all hooks are documented inside the wordpress codebase. You only need to read the code where the hook get's invoked to understand what the input values (and if a filter, the output values as well) mean. In your case that hook is located here: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3.1/wp-includes/functions.php#L513

Hope this helps.